# Random List of Products getting overwritten

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate a random Product list using the following method, but I'm getting the same Product instance multiple times.

```
Output for count 5:
Name: Qmlcloboa Price: 3.608848
Name: Qmlcloboa Price: 3.608848
Name: Qmlcloboa Price: 3.608848
Name: Qmlcloboa Price: 3.608848
Name: Qmlcloboa Price: 3.608848
```

I read on List type being a reference type & it overwrites stuff. Below is my code. am I missing something which could give me unique Product instances? Thanks & I would appreciate your help.

```
public List<Product> ProductGroupGenerator(int count)
    {
        List<Product> pList = new List<Product>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzeeeiouea";
            Func<char> randomLetter = () => alphabet[r.Next(alphabet.Length)];
            Func<int, string> makeName =
              (length) => new string(Enumerable.Range(0, length)
                 .Select(x => x == 0 ? char.ToUpper(randomLetter()) : randomLetter())
                 .ToArray());

            //string last = makeName(r.Next(7) + 7);
            //string company = makeName(r.Next(7) + 7) + " Inc.";

            string prodName = makeName(r.Next(5) + 5);
            int unitsInStock = r.Next(100);
            float unitPrice = (float)(r.NextDouble() * 10);

            Product p = new Product();
            p.Name = prodName;
            p.UnitsInStock = unitsInStock;
            p.UnitPrice = unitPrice;

            pList.Add(p);

            p = null;
        }

        return pList;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are getting the same value back from Random. That would make sense, since you reinit it every time you pass through the loop. Try moving your `Random r = new Random();` to occur before the for loop. That way you won't keep re-initing it back to give you the same answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When invoked too quickly, multiple `Random r = new Random()`'s will produce Randoms with identical seeds.

Declare it once outside the for loop and you should have better values.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
```

Comment: Yup; the default constructor seeds the generator based on the current system time. In a tight loop, the time will be the same for each time, so the same value will result from each call to get the 'first' number of the sequence.

Comment: That explains why it works when I have a breakpoint in there. Thanks. Will accept as answer in a few mins.

Answer (score 4):

Move the creation of the Random variable two lines to the top:

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
```

Otherwise you're always using the same seed for the random, because the for-loop is executed too fast. The `Random` constructor uses the current time. It is equivalent to new [`Random(Environment.TickCount)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx).

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite
>   resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in
>   close succession by a call to the default constructor will have
>   identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical
>   sets of random numbers. This problem can be avoided by using a single
>   Random object to generate all random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a single instance of `Random`, and using that during your `for` loop. Each time you create an instance of `Random`, it resets the seed, so you'll get the same value for each call.

Answer (score 0):

seed your random

```
Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

also, declare it outside of your loop.